# combined dictonaries by appending the value

Tags: python, dictionary

I just started learning the python and stuck with the dictionaries.

I wrote following sample program to merge two dictionaries:

```
dict4 = {}
dict1 = {'name' : 'Alice', 'Age' : '12'}
dict2 = {'name' : 'Apple', 'Age' : '13', 'Sex' : 'M'}
dict4 = dict.copy(dict1)

for i in dict2:
    if i not in dict4:
        dict4[i] = dict2[i]
    else:
        list(dict4[i]).append(dict2[i])
```

expected output is

```
dict4 = {'name' : ['Alice', 'Apple'], 'Age' : ['12', '13'], 'Sex' : ['', 'M']}
```

But I am seeing
dict4

```
{'name': 'Apple', 'Sex': 'M', 'Age': 13}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create the list, like this

```
for key in dict2:
    dict4[key] = [dict1.get(key, ''), dict2.get(key, '')]
```

**Note** that we use `dict2.get`, which accepts the default value to be returned if the current key is not found.

---

If you want to make sure that you want all the keys from both the dictionaries, create a set of keys from both the dictionaries like this

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for key in (dict1.keys() | dict2):
...     result[key] = [dict1.get(key, ''), dict2.get(key, '')]
...
>>> result
{'name': ['Alice', 'Apple'], 'Sex': ['', 'M'], 'Age': ['12', '13']}
```

---

You can still simply that by using a dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> {k: [dict1.get(k, ''), dict2.get(k, '')] for k in (dict1.keys() | dict2)}
{'name': ['Alice', 'Apple'], 'Sex': ['', 'M'], 'Age': ['12', '13']}
```

---

If you want to make it generic, with any number of dictionaries, you can use the following

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dicts = (dict1, dict2)
>>> result = {}
>>> for key in set(chain.from_iterable(dicts)):
...     result[key] = []
...     for d in dicts:
...         result[key].append(d.get(key, ''))
...         
>>> result
{'name': ['Alice', 'Apple'], 'Sex': ['', 'M'], 'Age': ['12', '13']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please let me know what we can do in case of multiple dictionaries?

Comment: @Vidyadhar I updated the answer to include a way to do this with N number of dictionaries. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this line:

```
list(dict4[i]).append(dict2[i])
```

does not modify the `dict4` at all.

And this line

```
 dict4[i] = dict2[i]
```

simply overwrite dict1's value with dict2's. It will not give a you a list.

Neither of them does what you want.

To achieve your expected result, try this:

```
result = {}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

for key, value in dict2.items():
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

As a simplification, you can do this

```
result = {}

for key, value in dict1.items() + dict2.items():
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [8]: final = dict((k, [dict1[k], dict2.get(k)]) for k in dict1)

In [9]: final.update((k, ['', dict2[k]]) for k in dict2 if k not in dict1)

In [10]: final
Out[10]: {'Age': ['12', '13'], 'Sex': ['', 'M'], 'name': ['Alice', 'Apple']}
```